# How can I make Javascript target the month?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Okay, so this is just theoretical to me, I have no code to help. Just saying :)

I was wondering that since it is possible, or at least I have seen it been done before, to make `if` statements with time i.e. `if (time>20)` is that possible to do with months? Or did the example I just mention (which I found on w3schools.com) actually use a variable without telling me haha.

What I'm really looking for is an if statement (hopefully simple) that resembles something like `if(month==1) {
//incorrect script follows
goTo(Id);};`

That example was hideous but the function it self is not what I'm looking for.

I was just curious about this and couldn't find anywhere that didn't have a page worth of code for something that, to me, looks so simple in the times we're in. I'll experiment with the code until someone can tell me. Thank you for your time : )

--------------------UPDATE!-----------------

I started working on it. And obviously this is not working for me. But this is what I tried. The idea is that when I open up or `style.display="block";` this `div` of mine, that it automatically calls the current month to show people the events happening that month.

```
    var now = new Date();
var month = now.getMonth();

var jan = document.getElementById("january");
var feb = document.getElementById("february");
var mar = document.getElementById("march");
var apr = document.getElementById("apri");
var may = document.getElementById("may");
var jun = document.getElementById("june");
var jul = document.getElementById("july");
var aug = document.getElementById("august");
var sep = document.getElementById("september");
var oct = document.getElementById("october");
var nov = document.getElementById("november");
var dec = document.getElementById("december");

var janHub = document.getElementById("janHub");
var augHub = document.getElementById("augHub");

function viewEvents (){
        eventsHub.style.display="block";
        mainBo.style.display="none";
        calender();
            };

function eventsX(){
            eventsHub.style.display="none";
            mainBo.style.display="block";};

function calender() {
    if (month==0) {
        jan.setAttribute("class", "current");
        janHub.style.display="block";
    }else if (month==7) {
        aug.setAttribute("class", "current");
        augHub.style.display="block";};

    };
```

Obviously I made the code you see as a test as it does not have all the `if`s for each month and etc.

------------------------UPDATE-----------------

This code works, I don't know if anyone else needs this but feel free to plunder it. It's pretty cool (to me anyways).

Comment: The [JavaScript Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

```
var now = new Date();
var month = now.getMonth();

if (month == 0)
    console.log('January');

if (month >= 2)
    console.log('March-December');
```

Or simply

```
if((new Date()).getMonth() == 11)
    console.log('December');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = new Date();
var month = today.getMonth();
```

Comment: please don't link to w3schools...or more appropriately w3fools...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date you are also creating unneeded variables.

Comment: Well something as simple as Date() I didn't think would hurt. I created the unneeded variables to help get the point across...

Comment: `var today = new Date();`
`var now = today.now();` do the same thing (you initialize a new Date which is for today...then you get today.now which doesn't do anything different....so the problem is you are just going to confuse poor new people who don't understand the `Date` object.

Comment: That is true, but new people might not understand that `new Date()` is the same. However, I have edited my comment.